# tensorflow exception from session initializing one variable?

Tags: tensorflow

I am getting an exception from tensorflow with this example code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2,2], stddev=0.35))
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session(init_op)
```

It gives

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'opts' referenced before assignment

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong? Maybe the example is too simple and Tensorflow expected more computations to be set up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the error is in your code, but that's an unhelpful error message from the `tf.Session` constructor.

The correct way to initialize the variable is:

```
sess = tf.Session()  # Note no argument.
sess.run(init_op)
```